# No instance for (MonadIO []) arising from a use of ‘liftIO’

Tags: haskell

I have this function:

```
canMoveTo2 :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)]
canMoveTo2 pos = do
    contents <- liftIO $ readFile "path_to_my_file"
    let currentPositions = [(digitToInt $ contents !! 0,digitToInt $ contents !! 1)]
    currentPositions
```

What I'm trying to do is read a file, storage its contents as a `string`, mount a `[(Int,Int)]` named `currentPositions` and return it.

The error I'm getting is:

```
No instance for (MonadIO []) arising from a use of ‘liftIO’
```

I'm learning haskell for about 1 month now, it seems like the problem is with some `instance`, but I really don't get what `instance` means. Can anyone help me understand this error and find a solution? I've come from a JS and PHP background.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot work with `liftIO` if the monadic context is a list. A list is not an "enriched" `IO`, like for example `MaybeT IO` is. It is thus not possible to use `readFile` to read a file if the output type of `canMove2` is a list.

You can make an `IO` monad that will produce a list with:

```
canMoveTo2 :: (Int,Int) -> IO [(Int,Int)]
canMoveTo2 pos = do
    c0 : c1 : _ <- readFile "path_to_my_file"
    pure [(digitToInt c0, digitToInt c1)]
```

You can perform this for example once in the `main`, and then pass the listof `currentPosition`s as parameter to another function.

Comment: Just to follow up on that, good software engineering practice has the separation of IO from application logic, so reading a file and then processing its contents in a single function is considered poor design. This is because it ties your application logic to a particular storage system. Haskell just happens to have a type system that pushes you into good practice.